# How to plot data on a world map in a Jupyter / iPython Notebook using pygal library?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pygal

I would like to visualize / display data on a world map in a Jupyter / iPython Notebook. I'm trying to use the high level [pygal library](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can also simply render the svg code generated by the pygal using IPython.display SVG

1. Install the pygal library

```
pip3 install pygal_maps_world
```

2. SVG rendering function

```
from IPython.display import SVG
 def display_svg(svg_code):
     return SVG(svg_code)
```

3. Code sample from pygal documentation

```
import pygal 
 worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
 worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
 worldmap_chart.add('F countries', ['fr', 'fi'])
 worldmap_chart.add('M countries', ['ma', 'mc', 'md', 'me', 'mg',
                                    'mk', 'ml', 'mm', 'mn', 'mo',
                                    'mr', 'mt', 'mu', 'mv', 'mw',
                                    'mx', 'my', 'mz'])
 worldmap_chart.add('U countries', ['ua', 'ug', 'us', 'uy', 'uz'])
 svg_code = worldmap_chart.render()
```

4. SVG rendering

```
display_svg(svg_code)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can render the HTML code generated by the pygal using IPython.display HTML. The main advantages are the more sophisticated javascript rendering with interactive features like the tooltips.

1. Install the pygal library

```
pip3 install pygal_maps_world
```

2. Create a basic html document which calls pygal rendering javascript libraries

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

html_doc = """
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://kozea.github.com/pygal.js/javascripts/svg.jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://kozea.github.io/pygal.js/2.0.x/pygal-tooltips.min.js""></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <figure>
       {rendered_chart}
     </figure>
   </body>
 </html>
 """
```

3. Code sample from pygal documentation

```
import pygal 
 worldmap_chart = pygal.maps.world.World()
 worldmap_chart.title = 'Some countries'
 worldmap_chart.add('F countries', ['fr', 'fi'])
 worldmap_chart.add('M countries', ['ma', 'mc', 'md', 'me', 'mg',
                                    'mk', 'ml', 'mm', 'mn', 'mo',
                                    'mr', 'mt', 'mu', 'mv', 'mw',
                                    'mx', 'my', 'mz'])
 worldmap_chart.add('U countries', ['ua', 'ug', 'us', 'uy', 'uz'])
```

4. HTML rendering

```
display(HTML(html_doc.format(rendered_chart=worldmap_chart.render(is_unicode=True))))
```

[image]